# Include editAttributes in R shiny module

Tags: r, mapping, shinymodules, r-mapedit

I still face problems to apply the `editAttributes()` function from the `mapedit` R-package into a shiny module. As soon As I modularize this function the data table corresponding to the rectangles is not reactive anymore. Below I provide a shortened example of the original code. The data table should be rendered as soon as a new rectangle has been added. With the first slider a value for the ractangle should be provided and stored as such. Works fine in shiny directly but not in module.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(mapedit)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(leafem)
library(tibble)
library(leafpop)
library(mapview)
library(htmltools)
library(tmaptools)
library(shinyWidgets)


APP_CRS <- 4326
le = TRUE 


user_crs <- APP_CRS
zoomto = "Berlin"
zoomto_area <- tmaptools::geocode_OSM(zoomto) 
zoomto <- sf::st_as_sfc(zoomto_area$bbox) %>% sf::st_sf() %>%
  sf::st_set_crs(APP_CRS)


dat <- data.frame(ES_value = 0) 

dat%>% 
  mutate(leaf_id = 1)


dat <- dat %>% mutate(leaf_id = 1:nrow(dat))
data_copy <- sf::st_as_sf(
  dat,
  geometry = 
    sf::st_sfc(lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)),function(i){sf::st_polygon()}))
) %>% sf::st_set_crs(APP_CRS)

########### map polygon selection module


mappingUI2 = function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
     mainPanel(
     
      editModUI(ns("map")),
      shiny::uiOutput(ns('dyn_form')),
      dataTableOutput(ns("tbl"))
   
    )) 
}

mapping_server2 = function(input, output, session, data_copy, dat,  zoomto, le){
      df <- shiny::reactiveValues(types = sapply(dat, class),
                                  data = data_copy,
                                  zoom_to = zoomto,
                                  edit_logic = le)

      shiny::observe({
        edits  <- callModule(
          module = editMod,
          leafmap = {
            mapv <- mapview::mapview(df$zoom_to,
                                     map.types = "CartoDB.Positron")@map %>%
              leaflet::hideGroup('df$zoom_to') %>%
              leafem::addFeatures(data = df$data,
                                  layerId = df$data$leaf_id,
                                  group = 'editLayer',
                                  popup = leafpop::popupTable(df$data))
            mapv},
          id = "map",
          targetLayerId = 'editLayer',
          sf = TRUE,

        )
      })


      proxy_map <- leaflet::leafletProxy('map-map', session)
      # render new row form based on the existing data structure


      shiny::observe({

        output$dyn_form <- shiny::renderUI({

          shiny::tagList(
            lapply(1:length(df$types), function(n){
              name <- names(df$types[n])
              label <- paste0(names(df$types[n]), ' (', df$types[n], ')')
              if (df$types[n] == 'character') {
                shiny::textInput(name, label, width = '100%')
              }  else if (df$types[n] %in% c('numeric','integer')) {
                shiny::sliderInput(name, label,1,5,3,1, width = '100%')
              }
            }),
            # we don't want to see this element but it is needed to form data structure
            htmltools::tags$script("document.getElementById('leaf_id-label').hidden
  = true; document.getElementById('leaf_id').style.visibility = 'hidden';")
          )

        })
      })


      output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable({

        n <- grep('leaf_id|geom', colnames(df$data)) # used to hide geometry/leaf_id column

        DT::datatable(
          df$data,
          options = list(scrollY="200px",
                         pageLength = 50,
                         scrollX = TRUE,
                         columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=n))),
          selection = "single",
          height = 200,
          editable = TRUE,
        )
      })

      proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('tbl')

      # modify namespace to get map ID
      nsm <- function(event="", id="map") {
        paste0(session$ns(id), "-", event)
      }

      EVT_DRAW <- "map_draw_new_feature"
      EVT_EDIT <- "map_draw_edited_features"
      EVT_DELETE <- "map_draw_deleted_features"

      #create a vector input for 'row_add'
      EVT_ADD_ROW <- "row_add"

      # determines whether to use 'row_add' or 'map_draw_feature'
      # also, if rows are selected then it won't trigger the 'map_draw_feature'
      addRowOrDrawObserve <- function(event, id) {
        shiny::observeEvent(
          if(is.na(id)){

            input[[event]]

          } else {

            input[[nsm(event, id = id)]]},{

              if(!is.null(input$tbl_rows_selected)){

              } else {

                # creates first column and row (must be more elegant way)
                new_row <- data.frame(X = input[[names(df$types[1])]])
                colnames(new_row) <- names(df$types[1])

                # remaining columns will be correct size
                for (i in 2:length(df$types)) {
                  new_row[names(df$types[i])] <- input[[names(df$types[i])]]
                }

                new_row <- sf::st_as_sf(new_row, geometry =
                                          sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point()), crs = APP_CRS)

                suppressWarnings({
                  # add to data_copy data.frame and update visible table
                  df$data <- df$data %>%
                    rbind(new_row)
                })

                # reset input table

              }
            })
      }

      addRowOrDrawObserve(EVT_ADD_ROW, id = NA)
      addRowOrDrawObserve(EVT_DRAW, id = 'map')

      addDrawObserve <- function(event) {
        shiny::observeEvent(
          input[[nsm(event)]],
          {

            evt <- input[[nsm(event)]]

            # this allows the user to edit geometries or delete and then save without selecting row.
            # you can also select row and edit/delete as well but this gives the ability to not do so.
            if(event == EVT_DELETE) {

              ids <- vector()

              for(i in 1:length(evt$features)){
                iter <- evt$features[[i]]$properties[['layerId']]
                ids <- append(ids, iter)
              }

              df$data <- dplyr::filter(df$data, !df$data$leaf_id %in% ids)
              df$ids <- ids

            } else if (event == EVT_EDIT) {

              for(i in 1:length(evt$features)){

                evt_type <- evt$features[[i]]$geometry$type
                leaf_id <- evt$features[[i]]$properties[['layerId']]
                geom <- unlist(evt$features[[i]]$geometry$coordinates)

                if (evt_type == 'Point') {
                  sf::st_geometry(df$data[df$data$leaf_id %in% leaf_id,]) <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point(geom))
                } else if (evt_type == 'Polygon'){
                  geom <- matrix(geom, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
                  sf::st_geometry(df$data[df$data$leaf_id %in% leaf_id,]) <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_polygon(list(geom)))
                } else if (evt_type == 'LineString'){
                  geom <- matrix(geom, ncol = 2, byrow = T)
                  sf::st_geometry(df$data[df$data$leaf_id %in% leaf_id,]) <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_linestring(geom))
                }
              }

            } else {

              # below determines whether to use 'row_add' or 'map_draw_feature' for adding geometries
              # if(!is.null(input$tbl_rows_selected)) {
              #   selected <- shiny::isolate(input$tbl_rows_selected)
              # }  else if (event == EVT_DRAW){
              selected <- length(input$tbl_rows_all) + 1
              # }

              skip = F

              # ignore if selected is null
              if(is.null(selected)) {skip = TRUE}

              # replace if draw or edit
              if(skip==FALSE) {
                sf::st_geometry(df$data[selected,]) <- sf::st_geometry(
                  mapedit:::st_as_sfc.geo_list(evt))

                #adding the leaf_id when we draw or row_add
                df$data[selected, 'leaf_id'] <-
                  as.integer(evt$properties[['_leaflet_id']])

              }
            }
          })

      }

      addDrawObserve(EVT_DRAW)
      addDrawObserve(EVT_EDIT)
      addDrawObserve(EVT_DELETE)


      # update table cells with double click on cell
      shiny::observeEvent(input$tbl_cell_edit, {

        df$data <- DT::editData(df$data, input$tbl_cell_edit, 'tbl',
                                resetPaging = F)
        DT::replaceData(proxy, df$data, rownames = FALSE, resetPaging = FALSE)

      })
    
}

### main app
ui <- shinyUI(
  mappingUI2("es_train")
)



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(mapping_server2,"es_train", data_copy,dat, zoomto, le)
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```